# How can I make the form tag wrap around two text areas and/or have the text areas on the opposite sides and responsive?

Tags: html, css, position

So I have these two text areas for a [Morse Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) translator that are in a form tag. One text area is in its default position, and the other is supposed to sit at the border of the other side of the space.

I have accomplished this with this code:

```css
#output {
    position:relative;
    right:-16.15px;
}

.textbox {
    font-size: .8rem;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-family: Palatino Linotype;
    padding:10px;
    line-height:1.5;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow:1.25px 1.25px 1.25px #777;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color:#222;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<form class="boxparent" method="post">
    <textarea class="textbox" id="input" rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="Enter text here"> </textarea>
    <textarea readonly class="textbox" id="output" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
</form>
```

How can I position this text area so that it's responsive and won't look wonky if the browser window is not 1920x1080?

I also have this button that I don't know how to make responsive:

```css
#switch {
    position: absolute;
    right:21.5rem;
    border-radius:20px;
    padding:7px;
    background-color:#444;
    color:#eee;
    border:1px solid #888;
}
```

```html
<button id="switch" href="morse.html">Translate to English</button>
```

This is how the page currently looks (the #de44e6 background was supposed to help with aligning the text areas):

[image]

Can anyone suggest how I can position these elements so they are responsive to the browser window?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> `display:flex;` and `flex-wrap:wrap` works;

```css
.boxparent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.textbox {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: Palatino Linotype;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1.25px 1.25px 1.25px #777;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #222;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
  <form class="boxparent" method="post">
    <textarea
      class="textbox"
      id="input"
      rows="10"
      cols="80"
      placeholder="Enter text here"
    >
    </textarea>
    <textarea
      readonly
      class="textbox"
      id="output"
      rows="10"
      cols="80"
    ></textarea>
  </form>
```